# How to read in Excel email attachments received in Outlook?

Tags: python, excel, outlook, win32com, office-automation

So I am trying to read in an Excel file from an attachment in Microsoft outlook. The code below works, but only while the email I am trying to read the attachment from is at the top of my inbox. How can I adjust my code so it looks at all emails in my inbox folder looking for the attachment or finding the emailed based on the subject provided. Also I would eventually like to have this work with a shared mailbox, but that is a secondary issue right now.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import email
import datetime as date
import os

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
val_date = date.date.today()

sub_today = 'subject of email'
att_today = 'Filename'


for msg in all_inbox:
    yourstring = msg.Subject.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    if(yourstring.find('"Filename"') != -1):
        break


for att in msg.Attachments:
    if att.FileName == att_today:
        attachments = msg.Attachments
        break

attachment = attachments.Item(1)
fn = os.getcwd() + '\\' + att_today
attachment.SaveASFILE(fn)
df = pd.read_excel(fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to iterate over all items you need to skip items, not break the loop. Use the [continue](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_continue.asp#:%7E:text=The%20continue%20keyword%20is%20used,continues%20to%20the%20next%20iteration.) keyword instead of `break` in the loop.

The Outlook object model provides the `Find`/`FindNext` and `Restrict` methods for getting items that correspond to your conditions. The store provider does the job more efficient than just iterating over all items in the folder. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

You can use the following search criteria where the query performs a phrase match query for `hello` in the message subject (VBA syntax):

```
filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001E" _
    & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch " & "'hello'"
```

To get a shared folder using the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared `Calendar` folder).